# katydids and things out on the front porch

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following sentence comes from the second part of the story 'GIRL' by O. Henry.

> You out-of-town chaps will be the people, with your **katydids** and moonlight and long drinks and **things out** on the front porch

What are **katydids** here and what does the speaker mean by 'things on the front porch'

Comment: 'Katydid' is in the dictionary. Questions that can be answered using a dictionary are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you search for images of a **katydid** in Google? It's an insect that you may find outside your house in the countryside.

@KateBunting has pointed that it's also known as *bush cricket* and that its name, katydid, *is apparently an imitation of the sound made by a species common in North America*.

[image: katydid]
*Image taken from [HobbyFarms](https://www.hobbyfarms.com/katydids-insects-summer-songs/)*

The author is explictily not being specific with what are those **other things** that you may find **out on the front porch**. You'll have to use your imagination. Think of any other things that you may find when you're out in a front porch located presumably in the countryside. Crickets? Birds? Songs accompanied with a banjo? It seems that the character didn't care to much about those things so he didn't mention them.

Comment: Otherwise known as a bush cricket. 'Katydid' is apparently an imitation of the sound made by a species common in North America.

Comment: @KateBunting Good point. Adding your comment to the answer. Thanks!